# Getting Exception : Here The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have facing Problem..

```
DataTable Dt1 = table1;
DataTable Dt2 =  Dt1.Copy();
DataRow[] row =  Dt1.Select("Name = 'Test'");

foreach (DataRow row in Dt2)
{
  Dt2.Rows.Remove(row); // Here The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection
}
```

Its giving the exception because I Filter the date from Different Row and Removing It from Different Row.

Thanks, Shivam

Comment: This should provide a compiler error, as row is redefined...  What's your actual code?

Comment: What is DataRow[] row =  Dt1.Select("Name = 'Test'");?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code removes all rows from the Dt2 DataTable because you overwrite the selected row from Dt1 when you loop through your foreach statement.